# How can I read a wave file and print the musical notes in western music on python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import wave, struct

waveFile = wave.open('sine.wav', 'r')

length = waveFile.getnframes()
for i in range(0,length):
    waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData)
    print(int(data[0]))
```

Comment: What happened when you ran this code? Be more comprehensive.

Comment: i want to print the notes of the file in western music, what should i do after this code?